# Why does vector of same size takes more memory than array in leetcode

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve [Ones and Zeros](https://leetcode.com/problems/ones-and-zeroes/) question from leetcode and for the same code but using vector occupies ~3x more memory than using array of same size. Here is my code that uses 3-D vector:

```
int findMaxForm(vector<string>& strs, int m, int n) {
    int S = strs.size();
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> dp(S+1, vector<vector<int>>(m+1, vector<int>(n+1, 0)));

    // int dp[S+1][m+1][n+1];
    // memset(dp, 0, sizeof dp);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    int zeros = count(strs[i].begin(), strs[i].end(), '0');
                    int ones = strs[i].length() - zeros;

                    if(zeros <= j && ones <= k) dp[i][j][k] = 1;
                    else dp[i][j][k] = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                int skip = dp[i - 1][j][k];
    
                int take = INT_MIN;
                int zeros = count(strs[i].begin(), strs[i].end(), '0');
                int ones = strs[i].length() - zeros;
                if(zeros <= j && ones <= k)
                    take = 1 + dp[i - 1][j - zeros][k - ones];

                dp[i][j][k] = max(skip, take);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return dp[S-1][m][n];
}
```

Submission details:

- Using `vector`: Runtime (~500ms); Memory **(102.6 MB)**
- Using `array`: Runtime (~500ms); Memory **(32.5 MB)**

Comment: That depends on the values of `S`, `m` and `n`. A `std::vector` usually has 3 pointers internally (`begin`, `end`, `capacity_end`), which is a lot of overhead when it has only a few elements.

Comment: in general a nested vector makes a rather poor multidimensional array.

Comment: Apart from what others have said, using `std::vector` is generally a Good Thing (tm), and it has a handly [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) function which might come in useful here.  It's not _guaranteed_ to do what you want, but it's definitely worth a shot.

Comment: Academic interest aside, I have 16 GB on my PC. So who cares about 70 MB extra? Did it solve the problem? Then it's good enough! In the real world, good enough is what counts.

Comment: A `vector<T>` of size `n` uses `sizeof(<vector<T>) + N * sizeof(T)` memory in total, where `N >= n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array (I assume you used plain C arrays) uses only as much memory as its elements. A vector uses some memory to store some housekeeping information like the length and location of the data.

Because you made a vector of vector of vectors, this housekeeping information is created for all of the nested vectors, which occupies a lot of space. This gets worse and worse if you increase the "dimension" of your "multidimensional" vector.

Comment: That equally applies to `std::array`, same 0 space overhead as C arrays.

Comment: Besides the bookkeeping data of the vector itself, there is a cost for each individual dynamic memory allocation made with the global allocator.